# Doctrine - extracting a column from a table

Tags: mysql, doctrine, symfony1

When I do something like this:

```
$boards = Doctrine_Query::create()
                        ->select('bds.id')
                        ->from('board bds')
                        ->whereIn('bds.type', $boardtype)
                        ->orderBy('bds.id')
                        ->execute();
```

the result $boards has more fields (columns) than what I wanted.  All I wanted was just a single array of table Board column Id.  Is there a way to do that?

I wanted to use the array in something like the following:

```
$buildings = Doctrine_Core::getTable('building')->createQuery('a')
                                                ->WhereIn('a.board_id', $boards)
                                                ->orderBy('a.id')
                                                ->execute();
```

However WhereIn only takes an array but not a query, so now I have to loop through $boards and generate an array of ID for WhereIn.

Therefore, I was wondering if I can retrieve a column as an array?  or if there is an alternative for what I'm doing.  Thank you for any help.

Background info:
Board has an many to one relationship with Building.  Id (key) column of Board is related to board_id column in Building.
What I want to achieve is generate a query of buildings that are associated with boards of given board types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read : http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/en/data-hydrators

```
$boards = Doctrine_Query::create()
                    ->select('bds.id')
                    ->from('board bds')
                    ->whereIn('bds.type', $boardtype)
                    ->orderBy('bds.id')
                    ->execute(array(), Doctrine_Core::HYDRATE_SINGLE_SCALAR);
```